# ItemsControl with none background WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I would like to ask you, if is possible to have ItemsControl without background (x:null), not transparent.

I have collection with data, and these are showed in ItemsControl with help of DataTemplate. Some data in datatemplate are collapsed, and I need to be able to clickable on another control behind the itemscontrol.

Here is example what I mean:

```
<Button x:Name="bt_behind"></Button>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfData}" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Class:Data}">
                     <Grid Width="100" Background="{x:Null}">
                          <Rectangle x:Name="rec" Fill="Red" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed">
                     </Grid>
                     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargeName="rec" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[Example where item3 is partly collapsed and marked area, where is empty place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovj9h.jpg)

I set everywhere the background to null (try itemcontainerstyle too), but without success. On button behind ItemsControl still is not clickable. I think that ItemsControl have transparent background for events, but is it possible to remove this background?

Thanks for any advice and sorry for my english:)

-pav-

Comment: It's worth to prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want someone else try your code (which is not even compile-able in current form). Did you try `IsHitTestVisible`?

Comment: It's all work with x:Null for Background... Don't know what's wrong with your code. Also, pls, fix your XAML in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as i said, it's all working. Fixed XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="bt_behind" Content="behind" Click="Bt_behind_OnClick"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfData}" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data}">
                <Grid Width="100" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rec" Fill="Red" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="rec" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Just for test.

```
private void Bt_behind_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I realised, that ItemsControl is inside of ScrollViewer. And ScrollViewer have custom HitTesting (background to null not working), so button can't be clicked. I forgot on it. I concentrated on ItemsControl. Very thanks for testing.